# How can I solve this variable issue?

Tags: android, variables, android-studio, global-variables, final

I know there are some questions like this , but none of the answers could solve my problem. So I'm gonna ask myself. How can I solve this problem? Sorry for don't specify more, I'm starting coding[image]

Answer (score 0):

A way of solving the problem would be to make the variable score1 a field variable, so after the declaration of the java class make a variable with private visibility and then increment that variable.

```
 public class Test{
    private int score1;
    //Constructor for the class for setting the variable.
    public Test(){
    score1 = 0 //Whatever the start value should be
    }
  }
```

All in all you now have a variable which can be "seen" from the inner class of the actionlistener.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
int score1=sharedPreferences.getInt("score",DEFAULT);
```

with

```
final int score1=sharedPreferences.getInt("score",DEFAULT);
```

or instead you declare score as a class variable

```
public class someclass{
 int score1;
 //here comes the rest of the code
}
```

good luck

Comment: Didn't work. I declare it as public and the same problem continues. I can't define it as final because its a Preference

Answer (score -1):

Declare score1 as a class attribute.